# 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' error when creating an image resizing function

Tags: python, function, computer-vision

I'm working on creating an image resizing function, and for some reason I'm receiving this error:

"'str' object has no attribute 'copy'"

The code I started with is

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image as mp_image

# Set a size for the figures
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

# Loop through subfolders
for root, folders, filenames in os.walk(src_folder):
    image_num = 0
    num_folders = len(folders)
    for folder in sorted(folders):
        # Increment the count of each image
        image_num +=1
        # Find the first image in the folder
        file_name = os.listdir(os.path.join(root,folder))[0]
        # Get the full path from the root folder
        file_path = os.path.join(root,folder, file_name)
        # Open the file using the matplotlib.image library
        image = mp_image.imread(file_path)
        # Add the image to the figure (which will have a row for each folder, each containing one column for the image)
        a=fig.add_subplot(num_folders, 1, image_num)
        # Add the image to the plot
        image_plot = plt.imshow(image)
        # Add a caption with the folder name
        a.set_title(folder)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

which resulted with three images successfully.

The problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to create a resizing function, and the code I'm using is as follows:

```
def resize_image(src_image, size=(200,200), bg_color="white"): 
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps 

    # resize the image so the longest dimension matches our target size
    src_image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Create a new square background image
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", size, bg_color)

    # Paste the resized image into the center of the square background
    new_image.paste(src_image, (int((size[0] - src_image.size[0]) / 2), int((size[1] - src_image.size[1]) / 2)))

    # return the resized image
    return new_image

# Resizing image
target_size = (128,128)
pad_color = "black"
resized_img = resize_image(file_path.copy(), target_size, pad_color)
n_h, n_w = resized_img.size
print('New size:', n_h, 'x', n_w)
imgplot = plt.imshow(resized_img)

plt.show()
```

I'm unsure why I'm receiving the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ac35b6ef00b6> in <module>
     17 target_size = (128,128)
     18 pad_color = "black"
---> 19 resized_img = resize_image(file_path.copy(), target_size, pad_color)
     20 n_h, n_w = resized_img.size
     21 print('New size:', n_h, 'x', n_w)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: file_path.copy(): file_path is a string, you can't use .copy() for it

Comment: What makes you think a `string` should have a `copy` method?